# Python - Module Not Found (No module named 'db')

Tags: python

**Running `python hello-world.py` results in the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/stream/processor.py", line 16, in <module>
     import db.mongo as mongo
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
```

**Is there anything I missed?**

Comment: Would be very helpful if you also include the code, and not only the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the packages? EG: `pip install [package]`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more information - such as complete code with identifiers removed, and complete output, python version and operating system? 
I ran the one line of code you mentioned in a simple setup on Windows 10 with Python 3.7 and it gives a different error than what you have shown here.

---

import db.mongo as mongo

---

outputs

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\script dir\testpy.py", line 3, in 
    import db.mongo as mongo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'